# Single Activity with multiple fragments, typical scenario. Struggling to achieve desired behavior

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an application running a single activity with multiple (2) fragments at a given time. I've got a fragment on the left which functions as a menu for which fragment to
display on the right hand side.

As an example lets say the menu consists of different sports; Football, Basketball, Baseball, Skiing, etc. When the user selects a sport, a fragment with details on the specific sport is displayed to the right.

I've set up my app to display two fragments at once in layout-large and layout-small-landscape. In layout-small-portrait however, only one fragment is displayed at a given time.

Imagine this; a user is browsing the app in layout-small-landscape (two fragments at a time) and selects a sport, Football. Shortly after he selects Basketball. If he now chooses to rotate into layout-small-portrait (one fragment at a time) I want the following to happen:

The Basketball fragment should be visible, but if he presses the back button, he should return to the menu and not to the Football fragment (!) which by default is the previous fragment in the back stack.

I have currently solved this like the following:

```
....

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // static fragments
    if(menuFragment == null) menuFragment = new MenuFragment();
    if(baseFragment == null) baseFragment = new TimerFragment(); // default content fragment

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

    // Determine what layout we're in..
    if(app().getLayoutBehavior(this) == LayoutBehavior.SINGLE_FRAGMENT) {
    // We are currently in single fragment mode

        if(savedInstanceState != null) {

            if(!rotateFromSingleToDual) {
                // We just changed orientation from dual fragments to single fragment!

                // Clear the entire fragment back stack
                for(int i=0;i<getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();i++) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                }

                ft.replace(R.id.fragmentOne, menuFragment); // Add menu fragment at the bottom of the stack
                ft.replace(R.id.fragmentOne, baseFragment);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }

            rotateFromSingleToDual = true;
            return;
        }

        rotateFromSingleToDual = true;

        ft.replace(R.id.fragmentOne, menuFragment);
    } else if(app().getLayoutBehavior(this) == LayoutBehavior.DUAL_FRAGMENTS) {
    // We are now in dual fragments mode

        if(savedInstanceState != null) {

            if(rotateFromSingleToDual) {
                // We just changed orientation from single fragment to dual fragments!
                ft.replace(R.id.fragmentOne, menuFragment);
                ft.replace(R.id.fragmentTwo, baseFragment);
                ft.commit();
            }

            rotateFromSingleToDual = false;
            return;
        }

        rotateFromSingleToDual = false;

        ft.replace(R.id.fragmentOne, menuFragment);
        ft.replace(R.id.fragmentTwo, baseFragment);
    }

    ft.commit();
}
```

This works, at least from time to time. However, many times I get java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: MenuFragment (....)

Can anyone please give me some pointers as to how to better implement this? My current code is not pretty at all, and I'm sure many developers out there want to achieve exactly this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using popBackStackImmediate to see if that helps your exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way to implement this scenario is to only use the fragment stack when in a mode that shows multiple fragments. When you're in the single fragment mode, you start a new activity that's sole job is to display the single fragment and take advantage of the activity back stack.

In your case you'll just need to remember the currently selected spot on rotate to set it as an argument when starting the new activity.

It's explained much better here:-

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! This helped significantly :)